# Como fazer um SELECT pra pegar o valor da última data cadastrada

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, pl-sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, oracle12c

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda pra sempre utilizar o valor de uma tabela.
Tenho uma tabela "CUSTOS" e todo mês ela sofre alteração de preço dos produtos, mais não são todos que tem atualização

A minha duvida, é que sempre que precisar utilizar a tabla CUSTO com a tabela PRODUTO, como faço para sempre chamar a ultima da data atualizada do produto. Vou mostrar o código que criei, porém não consigo aparecer o valor da ultima tabela de custo.

Des de já agradeço esse é um trecho resumido do estudo mais atende o básico que preciso explicar e entender.

```
CTE.DTCONTAGEM
,CTE.CODEMP
,PRO.NCM
,PRO.DESCRPROD
,CTE.CODPROD
,PRO.AD_PARTNUMBER
,CTE.CODVOL
,CTE.QTDEST

---na tabela de custo tem esse campo CUSSEMICM que preciso que seja sempre a ultima data inserida
,CUS.CUSSEMICM

-- esse código era só um teste porém traz qualquer valor do custo e não o ultimo
,(SELECT nvl(MAX(FCUS.CUSSEMICM), 0) 
  FROM TGFCUS FCUS
  WHERE FCUS.CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD
  AND FCUS.DTATUAL < trunc (SYSDATE) -1) AS CUSTO

,CUS.CUSSEMICM
,CTE.QTDEST * CUS.CUSSEMICM AS CUS_SEM_ICMS -- esse é o calculo que precisa fazer mais o custo tem que ser o certo
,CUS.CUSMEDCALC
,CTE.CODLOCAL
,CTE.CODPARC
,CTE.TIPO
FROM
VGFCTE CTE
LEFT JOIN TGFCUS CUS ON (CUS.CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD AND CUS.CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP AND CTE.CODLOCAL = CUS.CODLOCAL)
LEFT JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON (CTE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD )
WHERE CTE.TIPO ='P' AND (PRO.CODGRUPOPROD >= 30101000 AND PRO.CODGRUPOPROD <= 31601000)
AND CTE.CODLOCAL IN (10000000,20000000)
AND CTE.QTDEST > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

tente algo como

```
,CUS.CUSSEMICM

-- esse código era só um teste porém traz qualquer valor do custo e não o ultimo


,CUS.CUSSEMICM
,CTE.QTDEST * CUS.CUSSEMICM AS CUS_SEM_ICMS -- esse é o calculo que precisa fazer mais o custo tem que ser o certo
,CUS.CUSMEDCALC
,CTE.CODLOCAL
,CTE.CODPARC
,CTE.TIPO
FROM
VGFCTE CTE
LEFT JOIN TGFCUS CUS ON (CUS.CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD AND CUS.CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP AND CTE.CODLOCAL = CUS.CODLOCAL)
LEFT JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON (CTE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD )
WHERE CTE.TIPO ='P' AND (PRO.CODGRUPOPROD >= 30101000 AND PRO.CODGRUPOPROD <= 31601000)
AND CTE.CODLOCAL IN (10000000,20000000)
AND CTE.QTDEST > 0

AND CUS.CUSSEMICM = (SELECT nvl(MAX(FCUS.CUSSEMICM), 0) 
                      FROM TGFCUS FCUS
                      WHERE FCUS.CODPROD = CUS.CODPROD
                      AND   FCUS.CODEMP = CUS.CODEMP 
                      AND   FCUS.CODLOCAL = CUS.CODLOCAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, muito obrigado. Essa sacada não tinha me tocado, abriu minha mente. Refiz o código e deixei dessa forma baseado no que me passou.
Só tenho a agradecer.

```
       NCM,
       AD_PARTNUMBER,
       CTE.DTCONTAGEM, CTE.CODPROD,
       (SELECT DESCRPROD FROM TGFPRO WHERE CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD) AS PRODUTO, CTE.CODVOL,
       CTE.CODLOCAL || '-' ||
       (SELECT L.DESCRLOCAL FROM TGFLOC L WHERE L.CODLOCAL = CTE.CODLOCAL) AS LOCAL,
       CTE.QTDEST,  CASE WHEN CTE.TIPO = 'P' THEN 'PRÓPRIO' ELSE 'TERCEIROS' END AS TIPO,


NVL((SELECT NVL(MAX(CUSSEMICM),0)
     FROM TGFCUS
     WHERE CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD
     AND CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP
     AND DTATUAL = (SELECT MAX(DTATUAL)
                       FROM TGFCUS CN
                       WHERE CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD
                         AND DTATUAL <= CTE.DTCONTAGEM
                         AND CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP
                     )
      ) * CTE.QTDEST,0 ) AS CUS_SEMICMS,
CTE.CODEMP

,(SELECT NVL(MAX(CUSSEMICM),0)
     FROM TGFCUS
     WHERE CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD
     AND CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP
     AND DTATUAL = (SELECT MAX(DTATUAL)
                       FROM TGFCUS CN
                       WHERE CODPROD = CTE.CODPROD
                         AND DTATUAL <= CTE.DTCONTAGEM
                         AND CODEMP = CTE.CODEMP
                     )
      ) AS CUS_ITEM_SEMICMS

FROM TGFCTE CTE
INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON (CTE.CODPROD = PRO.CODPROD AND (PRO.CODGRUPOPROD >= 30101000 AND PRO.CODGRUPOPROD <= 31601000))
WHERE CTE.DTCONTAGEM = TO_DATE('24/12/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND CTE.CODEMP = 6
AND CTE.QTDEST > 0
```